# Phonegap jQueryMobile issue: lost data on switch off

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to Phonegap. I am using Phonegap2.3.0 for android and sqlite db. When I add datas in the tablet and switch off it all the datas are lost. Can I use localstorage.

Using SQLite Database Browser, I created a database and added some datas to each table and copied the .db file in assets folder.

Those datas are retrieved after switch off and the datas in the database that I entered through tablet is lost after switch off..

When I exit the app, I got the text as 
   onDestroy()
   Killing (package name) : remove task
   Process: (package name) has died

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you are attempting to add data? How about posting some code which isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `localStorage.setItem("keyString", value)` and `localStorage.getItem("keystring")`

and you can also use local db

```
function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
     tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I used localStorage to get a name value and inserted it into database and got an insertId. But the datas are lost onDestroy(). Could you please give a code to save the database onDestroy() or onPause() function.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not true... local data will be lost...
I'm having the same issue...
While ever the app is running data is available but lost as soon as app is ended or tablet is rebooted.
The same issue for SQLite...

I'm using Eclipse, JQM and phonegap API and i can update both local store and SQLite database confirm that data is updated and then when i close the app and restart it the data is not there.....

native local storage (persistent) and SQLite have commit methods but these are not documented on phonegap and not available through their API using version 1.4.1 PhoneGap as is requirement of project for compatibility. issue with persistent local storage is that the user can delete it.

any one else got any answers?????

Comment: OK i sussed...
There is not a lot of info about this but when using SQLite and it's the best option for permanent data after your updates you need to COMMIT the changes a simple `code` tx.executeSql("COMMIT"); `code` as part of your success call back will make sure that data is permanently stored.

hope this helps....